# Dynamic form into mysql database

Tags: php, html, jquery, forms, dynamic

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/othjkw1f/)

I am trying to insert data into mysql database using dynamic forms.

Html:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Dynamic forms </title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
   <!-- Navbar content -->
    <a class="navbar-brand text-white">Dynamic_form</a>
</nav>
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="card text-center">
            <div class="card-header">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs">
                    <li class="nav-item"> 
                      <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Forms</a>
                    </li>
               </ul>
           </div>
           <div class="card-body">
              <h4 class="card-title">Test</h4>
              <p class="card-text"></p>
              <form action="" id="needs-validation" novalidate>
                  <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                        <input type="number" id="input1" class="input form-control" placeholder="Enter number of forms" required>
                     </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <div class="text-center">
                           <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary generate" id="btn1" type="submit">Generate tripleroom</button>
                       </div>
                    </div>
              </form>
                    <p class="card-text"></p>
                    <form action="" id="needs-validation" novalidate>
                  <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                        <input type="number" id="input2" class="input form-control" placeholder="Enter number of forms" required>
                     </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <div class="text-center">
                           <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary generate" id="btn2" type="submit">Generate doubleroom</button>
                       </div>
                    </div>
              </form>
           </div>
        </div>
</div>
       <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="card text-center">
               <div class="card-body">
                   <div class="forms">
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.card').css('margin-top', 30);
$('#btn1').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
let input1 = $('#input1').val();
let temp_html = '';
for(i = 0; i < input1; i++){
temp_html += '<form id="form1" action="welcome.php" method="post">'+ 
            '<div class="row">'+
                '<div class="col-md-4">'+
                    '<div class="form-group">'+
                    '<label>Fullname</label>'+ 
                    '<input type="text" name="fullname[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Fullname" required="">'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div>'+
                '<div class="col-md-4">'+
                    '<div class="form-group">'+
                    '<label>Email Address</label>'+ 
                    '<input type="email" name="email[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required="">'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div>'+
                '<div class="col-md-4">'+
                    '<div class="form-group">'+
                    '<label>Mobile Number</label>'+
                    '<input type="text" name="phone[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone number" value="Tripleroom" readonly required="">'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div>'+
              '</form>'+
            '</div>';
            }
$('.forms').append(temp_html);
});
});
</script>

<button id="submit">Submit</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById( 'submit' ).addEventListener( 'click', function () {
    // check for and report errors here
    for( var index = 0; index < document.forms.length; index++ ) {
        document.forms[index].submit();
    }
} );
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.card').css('margin-top', 30);
$('#btn2').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
let input2 = $('#input2').val();
let temp_html = '';
for(j = 0; j < input2; j++){
temp_html +='<form id="form1" action="welcome.php" method="post">'+ 
            '<div class="row">'+
                '<div class="col-md-4">'+
                    '<div class="form-group">'+
                    '<label>Fullname</label>'+ 
                    '<input type="text" name="fullname[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Fullname" required="">'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div>'+
                '<div class="col-md-4">'+
                    '<div class="form-group">'+
                    '<label>Email Address</label>'+ 
                    '<input type="email" name="email[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required="">'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div>'+
                '<div class="col-md-4">'+
                    '<div class="form-group">'+
                    '<label>Mobile Number</label>'+
                    '<input type="text" name="phone[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone number" value="Doubleroom" readonly required="">'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div>'+
                '</form>'+
            '</div>';
}
$('.forms').append(temp_html);
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

First I am just trying to print the results using php:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$qty = $_POST['fullname'];

if (is_array($qty)) {
   for ($i=0;$i<count($qty);$i++)
   {
       print_r ($qty[$i]);
   }
}
?><br>


</body>
</html>
```

The issue is that I only get data from the last generated form. For example, if I generate 2 forms, I only get the data from the second.

How do I submit all data from the dynamically generated forms ?

All and any help is appreciated. I think I have tunnel vision right now, as I've been trying to get to the bottom of this the last few days.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing

```
document.forms[index].submit();
```

the broswer automatically goes to welcome.php without actually submitting any of the other forms. If you want to create a dynamic form you should save the data in an object/array or some other form and send all the data to welcome.php through one form instead of creating multiple different forms.

If you however would like to keep different forms you would need to send your data using AJAX.